# Modify a VBA code to drag down sumifs to a large number of rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code in part of my excel vba that I need to amend but could do with some help understanding.

In cells T, W, and Z there is a sum if formula in row 2, this VBA replicates this formula down to the last row. I am trying to update the formula so that it does this for column T,W,Z,AC and AF

I've changed the 1-3 to 1-5 but it is debugging at the doc(ii) line.

Please could anyone help me up understand and update it.

```
    Dim a, k, i As Long, ii As Long, t As Long, w(1 To 3), x, dic(1 To 3) As Object
    With Range("k2", Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        k = .Value
        a = .Columns(8).Resize(, 10).Value
    End With
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set dic(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dic(i).CompareMode = 1
        ReDim x(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 1) As Double: w(i) = x
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        For ii = 1 To 3
            dic(ii)(a(i, (ii - 1) * 3 + ii + 1)) = i
        Next
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        For ii = 1 To 3
            t = (ii - 1) * 3 + ii
            If dic(ii).exists(a(i, t)) Then
                x = w(ii)
                x(dic(ii)(a(i, t)), 1) = x(dic(ii)(a(i, t)), 1) + k(i, 1)
                w(ii) = x
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(2, (i + 4) * 4).Resize(UBound(a, 1)).Value = w(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim a, k, i As Long` only `i` is of type `Long` but `a` and `k` are of type `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default: `Dim a As Long, k As Long, i As Long`. • Further I highly recommend to use meaningful variable names. 1 or 2 letter names are awful to read and remember what each variable is. Meaningful names result in less errors and the code is much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: As the code is now, it is almost impossible to understand what your code actually does and even harder to understand what you expect it to do. Please check [mcve] and provide a proper example of what is going wrong.

Comment: You'd need to also change this declaration `dic(1 To 3)` but it's not clear which code you are using as it doesn't tally with your description. Also please clearly state whch line errors.

Comment: Hi both, thank you for the reply. Ive never used scripting dictionaries before so was struggling but want to learn.

Comment: Basically in columns T, W, Z, AC, AF row 2, I have a sumif formula, so for column T (Sumif($U:$U,$V2,$K:$K). With columns W, Z, AC and AF the range and criteria are the previous two columns, the sum range remains K on all of them

Comment: I was using the code Range("T2:T" & Range("AH1").value.Filldown to copy this formula but due to the number of rows (counted in AH1) it was taking over 10mins to run the VBA

Comment: I've tried to change any part of the script that says 1-3 to 1-5 but it debugs at dic(ii) (a(i, (ii - 1) * 5 + ii + 1)) = i